# Android app always pick drawable from XXXHDPI directory

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, hdpi

I am developing an application, and I defined 5 different sizes of drawables in my app. But when I run the app, it always run with xxxhdpi drawable files.
Is there any simple way to configure app to pick suitable drawable depend on android device?
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) are you sure you don't have same files in all your drawable folders by mistake? b) how do you know it's using drawables from xxxhdpi folder

Comment: I am shure I don't have same files in dravables. after put the drawables file in to drawable folders images I rebuild the project and check the image source from layout. There it shows which drawable folder is using for the applicaton.

Comment: This works out of the box if you did it right. Show how you access this drawable.

Comment: ivProfileImage.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.user_image));
This how I am accessing drawable @Henry